# Fitting shifted and deformed dataset to dataset in python

Tags: python, data-manipulation, data-fitting

I am trying to analyze the shift and deforming of a pressure test on a block of concrete.
I have two measurements: one of a height (vector h) and one of the diameter (vector d) at that specific height. I have these measurements for different pressures deforming the block. I will denote the height and diameter for different pressures with the index i (h_1 to h_n, d_i respectively). len(h_i) is not necessarily equal to len(h_j)
I want to find a way to fit (deform and shift) the graph

G_1 = (h_1, d_1) to the graph

G_2 = (h_2, d_2)
I thought of minimizing the square error like it is done in functional fitting, I do however have some problems:

1. I do not know how to introduce the shift in the height/ x-direction

   i.e. f(h_(i+1))=f(h_i - h_shift)
2. I do not know how to introduce the compression in the height/ x-direction

   i.e. f(h_(i+1))=f(a*h_i )
3. I am not sure how I can introduce the "normal" fitting deforming diameter depending on the height. (say I want to add a deforming of the form d_(i+1)=d_i+a*h²+b*h+c)

I want to stress again that I do not try to manipulate a function to fit data-points but that I try to manipulate a set of points to fit a different set of points.

UPDATE: I have stored illustrations [here on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CQL6nhADTwWDSXQewq2BsMQty0ZiQqA3?usp=sharing)

Note that there are two different kinds of shift: one small one (sample_fitting_1.png) and one large one (sample_fitting_2.png).

I am trying not to loose the fine structure of the data as I would by fitting a curve through it.

The goal is to shift and deform one of the graphs onto the other one by manipulating it as described above as well in x as in y-direction.

Thanks in advance

Stephan

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to do, maybe it would be helpful if you include a small data sample in the question

Comment: unfortunately I cannot put the data online at the moment but I have added illusatrations (update in question). I hope this helps